# How to coordinate J2EE and Java EE database access?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

We have a somewhat huge application which started a decade ago and is still under active development. So some parts are still in J2EE 1.4 architecture, others using Java EE 5/6.

While testing some new code, I realized that I had data inconsistency between information coming in through old and new code parts, where the old one uses the Hibernate session directly and the new one an injected EntityManager. This led to the problem, that one part couldn't see new data from the other part and thus also created a database record, resulting in primary key constraint violation.

It is planned to migrate the old code completely to get rid of J2EE, but in the meantime - what can I do to coordinate database access between the two parts? And shouldn't at some point within the application server both ways come together in the Hibernate layer, regardless if accessed via JPA or directly?

Comment: I would suggest you introduce database locking, instead of session transaction level isolation as they are being managed by different connections. something like @Version may help

Comment: Hm, I wonder if in this case the answer is to use distributed transactions rather than locking. Its a bit vague but I get the idea that the problem is that the "old code" and "new code" are needlessly working in isolated transactions and should in fact work within the same transaction.

Comment: @Gimby: To clarify, information coming in and being processed in old and new parts are separated use cases - I would only need a common persistence context for both, so that both parts see the same data.

Comment: @maress: I do have a version column in database, used by the Entity. So what should be done to use that same field in the old J2EE DAO?

Comment: I guess in the old J2EE DAO you may have to have some generic way just before persist or update occurs to confirm that the column value for @Version field has not changed. If you look at hibernate (i really cant tell now at which point) but there must be away you can hook some interceptors before persist/update and confirm that the field has not changed

Comment: If you have a centralized way of getting you session in old code, you could considere to simply modify it and extract the hibernate session from the `EntityManager` (or the `SessionFactory` from the `EntityManagerFactory`).

Comment: How do you access to the hibernate session in old code ?

Comment: Do you ship Hibernate with the application or you you use Hibernate from your application server?

Comment: Is your problem that you're trying to commit two unrelated records and they each get the same (generated) sequence number as their primary key when they should get unique values?  Or is the problem that two pieces of code are both trying to commit a record for the same entity because it doesn't exist in either of their sessions when they start, but it's then rejected as a duplicate entity once they both commit?

Comment: @Tim: The latter one.

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall: Would that make any difference? I can't check at the moment, since I'm out of office, but I assume it's JBOss' Hibernate implementation.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: As stated before, I can't check right now, but as I remember, we'll get it from the SessionFactory.

Comment: @Geziefer could you show us how you get the SessionFactory and the EntityManager (also show us xml files). I assume you have that problem with certain entities and certain use cases. Given that, did you try to switch both parts (old & new) to the same way (either EntityManager, or SessionFactory)?

Comment: @AndreiI: I will do so when I'm back in office. I haven't tried to switch something yet, since it's a comparable complex application and by trying to find possible solutions to the problem, I also try to estimate costs for implementing this temporal solution vs. migrating old code, which has to be done sooner or later.

Comment: @Geziefer yes, if the JPA implementation is different from Hibernate (eg. JPA from the server but Hibernate from the application) that would explain your issues

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall: I checked, that we don't ship Hibernate, but use the one supplied from JBoss 7.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: I checked, that we get `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` by calling `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory()` and then `org.hibernate.Session` by calling `mySessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession()`.

Comment: @AndreiI: See answer to your comment above. The `EntityManager` is injected via `@PersistenceContext`. Which parts of XML might additionally be interesting?

Comment: @Geziefer : If it is an option to replace the `buildSessionFactory` call, please see my answer below.

Comment: Are you using JavaEE standard persistence? Does your application deployment contains it's own copy of Hibernate? Are you using the JTA transaction manager in the Hibernate configuration? How is transaction demarcation managed? Are you using (possibly stateless) session beans for this purpose?

Comment: @SteveC: The new part uses JPA 1.0, the old part Hibernate. As said, we don't provide Hibernate, it's taken from JBoss 7. In old parts, transactions are done manually, but using container's JTA. In new part, container does everything. EJBs are used in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you instanciate separately a `SessionFactory` for the old code and an `EntityManagerFactory` for new code, that can lead to different value in first level cache. If during a single Http request, you change a value in old code, but do not immediately commit, the value will be changed in session cache, but it will not be available for new code until it is commited. Independentely of any transaction or database locking that would protect *persistent* values, that mix of two different Hibernate session can give weird things for in memory values.

I admit that the injected EntityManager still uses Hibernate. IMHO the most robust solution is to get the `EntityManagerFactory` for the `PersistenceUnit` and cast it to an Hibernate `EntityManagerFactoryImpl`. Then you can directly access the the underlying `SessionFactory`  :

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.getSessionFactory();
```

You can then safely use this `SessionFactory` in your old code, because now it is unique in your application and shared between old and new code.

You still have to deal with the problem of session creation-close and transaction management. I suppose it is allready implemented in old code. Without knowing more, I think that you should port it to JPA, because I am pretty sure that if an `EntityManager` exists, `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` will give its underlying `Session` but I cannot affirm anything for the opposite.

Comment: I got some nice insights from all comments, but I rate this proposal best and will see how to work with it. As I said, the future plan is to completely get rid of J2EE parts and direct Hibernate usage, but in the meantime it may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can mix both Hibernate Session and Entity Manager in the same application without any problem. The [EntityManagerImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/internal/EntityManagerImpl.html) simply delegates calls the a private [SessionImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/internal/SessionImpl.html) instance.

What you describe is a Transaction configuration anomaly. Every database transaction runs in isolation (unless you use REAN_UNCOMMITED which I guess it's not the case), but once you commit it the changes are available from any other transaction or connection. So once a transaction is committed you should see al changes in any other Hibernate Session, JDBC connection or even your database UI manager tool.

You said that there was a primary key conflict. This can't happen if you use Hibernate identity or sequence generator. For the [old hi-lo generator](http://vladmihalcea.com/from-jpa-to-hibernates-legacy-and-enhanced-identifier-generators/) you can have problems if an external connection tries to insert records in the same table Hibernate uses an old hi/lo identifier generator.

This problem can also occur if there is a master/master replication anomaly. If you have multiple nodes and there is no strict consistency replication you can end up with primar key constraint violations.

**Update**

Solution 1:

When coordinating the new and the old code trying to insert the same entity, you could have a slect-than-insert logic running in a SERIALIZABLE transaction. The SERIALIZABLE transaction acquires the appropriate locks on tour behalf and so you can still have a default READ_COMMITTED isolation level, while only the problematic Service methods are marked as SERIALIZABLE.

So both the old code and the new code have this logic running a select for checking if there is already a row satisfying the select constraint, only to insert it if nothing is found. The SERIALIZABLE isolation level prevents phantom reads so I think it should prevent constraint violations.

Solution 2:

If you are open to delegate this task to JDBC, you might also investigate the [MERGE SQL statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29), if your current database supports it. Basically, this is an upsert operation issuing an update or an insert behind the scenes. This command is much more attractive since you can still run it with even on READ_COMMITTED. The only drawback is that you can't use Hibernate for it, and only some databases support it.

Comment: You are right, once it's _committed_, but I think the problem is, that each of the two different ORM components checks for an existing record with a given id at pretty much the same time and since none is found tries to insert a new record, which leads to a PK violation for one of them.

Comment: What identifier generator are you using?

Comment: I'm using this in the entity (Java EE): `@GenericGenerator(name="abc", strategy="sequence", parameters = {@Parameter(name="sequence", value="xyz")})  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "abc")`

Comment: And this in the `.hbm.xml` mapping file (J2EE): `<id name="id" type="long"> <column name="id" /> <generator class="sequence"> <param name="sequence">xyz</param> </generator> </id>`

Comment: Because you use the GenericGenerator, you can actually point to the actual Hibernate identifier generator. The "sequence" generator is always calling the database for a new identity value, so there is no way a clash can ever happen unless you have multi-nodes and a replication failure. The database sequence ensures value uniqueness, so it's not Hibernate who's failing on you.

Comment: I see, so maybe it comes from the fact that there used to be a combination of columns which together formed a cobined primary key and which are now replaced by a technical id and a constraint checking for it, which still might have the misleading name pk_... But still, the problem is one step back, that both components try an insert due to thinking the record has not yet been stored. And that's why I assumed, that one centralized entity manager would care for it, or am I making a mistake?

Comment: The entity manager delegates this responsibility to identifier generators. If you still have both running then ensuring uniqueness should be delegated to DB. It's always safer that way.

Comment: @VladMihalcea, based on the OP's comments, this is not related to identifier generation, it's due to separate sessions both trying to save the same entity simultaneously.  This is about unique constraints on natural keys, **not** generating identical synthetic IDs.

Comment: I'm a little bit puzzled now. The question said "primary key constraint violation.". Hibernate [natural key](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-naturalid) has more of a logical business key meaning, but it doesn't play a role in the identifier primary key assignment.

Comment: @VladMihalcea: Maybe I was not clear here - the table used to have a combined primary key in old code, then a technical PK was introduced, but still the combination of the fields formerly defined as PK have to be unique.

Comment: I added an update. Hope it helps. Basically you could use SERIALIZABLE or MERGE.

Comment: One thing to consider if you go down the path of using SERIALIZABLE: you will hold the lock for the duration of the transaction, which will block the other threads until the transaction commits.  If you go down this path, make sure you minimize the amount of time spent in the transaction by doing everything you can before starting the transaction, to minimize the performance impact.

Comment: I think every of those solutions has its big disadvantage: 1.It is not easy (no standard way) to set the transaction isolation level in an EJB (compared to Spring). Also using SERIALIZABLE could bring you some other performace problems. 2. I really advice against working on the JDBC level, as you will waste your time probably reinventing partially the wheel.

Comment: @Vlad, I really do not want to be rude, I simply consider those solutions are simple ideas that will not help solving OP's problem . 1) As an example: could you provide an example on how to set the transaction level on a specific method in the JBOSS/Wildfly AS? 2)Second solution is about JDBC, not about Hibernate. You are free to add a third solution with data knowledge stack.

Comment: @AndreiI I know how to set it in [WebLogic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs81/doc/en/core/index.html). The data knowledge stack is about getting the best from your available tools. If you don;t like any of those please provide us a better one and we'll all learn something.

Comment: @VladMihalcea I work with JBoss for years and do not know for any solutions of setting the transaction isolation level except on connection level. So may you should specify that some Application Servers support that, but possibly not all. Also I would MAY BE come with a solution, but I am afraid OP did not provide ANY details on how injecting, transaction propagation, configuration is made.

Comment: Back in J2EE days when I was developing an app running on JBoss, there used to be a specific ejb xml descriptor where the transaction properties could be overridden for each EJB method. Alternatively, you could use BMT and set: connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE); before starting a transaction and reset it back to the previous value right before existing.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar problem when I had a list of enumerated lookup values, where two pieces of code would check for the existence of a given value in the list, and if it didn't exist the code would create a new entry in the database.  When both of them came across the same non-existent value, they'd both try to create a new one and one would have its transaction rolled back (throwing away a bunch of other work we'd done in the transaction).

Our solution was to create those lookup values in a separate transaction that committed immediately; if that transaction succeeded, then we knew we could use that object, and if it failed, then we knew we simply needed to perform a `get` to retrieve the one saved by another process.  Once we had a lookup object that we knew was safe to use in our session, we could happily do the rest of the DB modifications without risking the transaction being rolled back.

It's hard to know from your description whether your data model would lend itself to a similar approach, where you'd at least commit the initial version of the entity right away, and then once you're sure you're working with a persistent object you could do the rest of the DB modifications that you knew you needed to do.  But if you can find a way to make that work, it would avoid the need to share the Session between the different pieces of code (and would work even if the old and new code were running in separate JVMs).